# What all tools needed to design/publish websites?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, web

I am currently in the process of learning web design. I have learned Java, HTML, SQL, Python and am working on CSS and Javascript. I am learning these because the names of these languages pop up alot when i read about web design. So far i have seen the power of HTML, i can type code and open it as a HTML page and it's a webpage. My question is, what to do when you have all the tools to make the website? How does this website get to be on the World Wide Web? I have done a lot of research and i just don't think i understand the logic behind it. I see that i can purchase a domain name, but how do i bridge the gap between, lets say a simple HTML webpage and getting it to pop up on google? Thanks guys!

Comment: Once you publish a website, it's only a matter of time until google indexes it.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. You're asking for the complete A-Z of how to build/publish a website, which definitely falls under "too broad".

Comment: But how do i get the website onto the purchased domain?

Comment: Lots of stuff but this is the short version: you upload it to a server. That server has a public IP. DNS servers create an entry that matches `my-domain.com` with that public IP. Hitting `my-domain.com` automatically redirects to the server and data is sent over a port.

Comment: Is that process pretty much laid out for you once you purchase the domain?

Comment: @NoobyHacker Most of the time, you'll purchase a domain and get web hosting through some 3rd party. That 3rd party will tell you how to setup the connection between them and your domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain register (GoDaddy for example) will point your domain to your hosting server (using the domain name servers or DNS for short), then your hosting server will serve your HTML/PHP/CSS files to anyone requesting them.

Using the submit URL link on google (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) you can tell Google "hey, i got a new domain, come and check it out!" so Google will index it shortly (may vary between 2-14 days.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted!! Thank you very much

Comment: SO if i purchase the domain right now and make a VERY simple html webpage in notepad, i could have a functional reachable webpage up within an hour?

Comment: Yes, probably. Most of the registers offer hosting with the new domains so: Purchase domain, configure the DNS to your hosting (or have it preconfigured in the case of godaddy), upload your file and you're done.

Comment: Should i be worried about learning PHP or anything else? I feel like for a website for my band, which doesn't really require user accounts or anything with security, i could get away with just using javascript and html. Or do i need to take further measures to ensure that the website won't be taken down? I mean how secure would a very basic HTML5 textpad website be when hooked up to Godaddy hosting and domain server?

Comment: With no user interaction (no forms being sent, no way for the user to input their own data) you pretty much don't have to worry about being attacked. If you use javascript for something funky, like sending mails or posting data somewhere else, you should sanitize all the inputs and care a lot about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server to host it on.  The easiest way to do this is to use a cloud service such as Amazon's AWS.  In fact, if all you are building is a static html/javascript webpage, you can probably just host it on s3.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html